# Expanding App Testing: Generating and Installing Files on iPhones with React Native and Expo

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm currently developing a mobile application using React Native and Expo.
To conduct testing on Android, I generate an APK file.

I would like to know if it's possible to generate and install a similar file on iPhones, just like on Android. Do I need to have a developer account?

I have already tried the following command: eas build -p ios --profile preview.